# Tools to predict the number of executors, executor cores and executor memory

Tags: apache-spark

While Running a spark job we need to pass values for  number of executors, executor cores and executor memory. I am trying to make a ml model which will predict this for a certain spark job based on various features like job complexity, time in which job should finish, input/output data size, such that the job finishes in time by using optimal amount of cluster resources.
I just wanted to know is there some tool already available for such use case or tools which can help in such use case.

I am not trying to calculate the number of executors and cores based on hardware specification. What I am trying to find is that for a particular job what configurations should I have, currently we do it by experimenting with different values and picking one of them